# setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock and RKPaginator

Tags: restkit

I try to setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock to a RKPaginator object with the following code:

```
[[self.paginator objectRequestOperation] setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:^id(id deserializedResponseBody) {

        return deserializedResponseBody;
    }];
```

But the objectRequestOperation is nil. Does anyone can help me with where to define the willMapDeserializedResponseBlock: to a RKPaginator ?

Thank